# I want to create a reverse proxy setup for my shopify store and link it to a subfolder (/shop) route in my current application

Tags: nginx, dns, shopify, nginx-reverse-proxy, subdirectory

I have a store on shopify and i want to expose but i don't want to use a subdomain, i want to route it to a subfolder in my current web application.
ideal flow when user goes to mydomain/shop it should it act mirror the shopify store

I have access to the server(Linux, NGINX) and DNS (Cloudflare)

from some resaerch this is my current conf file.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mydomain;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:9004;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        client_max_body_size 10m;
        client_body_buffer_size 128k;

        proxy_connect_timeout 90; # time to connect to upstream server
        proxy_send_timeout 120; # time to wait for upstream to accept data
        proxy_read_timeout 120; # time to wait for upstream to return data

        proxy_buffer_size 4k;
        proxy_buffers 4 32k;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_busy_buffers_size 64k;
        proxy_temp_file_write_size 64k;
    }


    location /shop {
        proxy_pass https://myshopifystore.com;
        proxy_set_header Host myshopifystore.com;
        client_max_body_size 10m;
        client_body_buffer_size 128k;
        proxy_connect_timeout 90;
    }
}
```

any help will be greatly appreciated.

I'm getting retirected to my shopify-page password route but it its treating it as an internal path and throwing 404 on my application.